# Clip Path not working in an SVG element

Tags: svg, clip, clipping

I'm trying to get a rectangular `<clipPath>` to clip a `<circle>` in an SVG element, but I can't seem to get it work.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/jpLMaV

Em

```css
#circle {width: 10rem;}
```

```html
<defs>
  <clipPath id="myClipPath">
    <rect x="30" y="30" width="100" height="100"/>
  </clipPath>
</defs>

<svg id="circle" style="clip-path: url(#myClipPath)" viewBox="0 0 391 391">
  <circle fill="#000" cx="195.5" cy="195.5" r="195"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget `<svg>` around your clip path declaration .

```
<svg width=0 height=0 >
<defs>
  <clipPath id="myClipPath">
   <rect x="50px" y="50px" width="200px" height="200px"/>
  </clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>

<svg style="clip-path: url(#myClipPath)" id="circle" width="400" height="400">  
  <circle fill="#000" cx="100px" cy="100px" r="100px"/> </svg>
```

edit: i simplified and i added a witdh and height attribute

Comment: That still doesn't seem to work as expected though? It pushes the circle further out and seems to add to the circle as opposed to clipping it — I've updated the codepen.

Comment: You need to set the width and height of the first SVG to 0, as @EchoMike444 has done. Otherwise that SVG takes up space on the page. https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/bjoPrM